# How to move decimal point to the left in proc freq/proc tabulate percentage output?

Tags: sas, decimal-point

I am creating a table using proc tabulate, but I need my percentage output to be 0.81 instead om 81 %. I have tried using the picture format, but it isn't quite right. At the moment my output just shows 0 instead of 0,81.

I have posted my code below:

```
Data have; 
input gender q1 year;
lines;
0  0  2014
0  1  2014
0  1  2014
0  1  2014
0  0  2014
1  1  2014
1  1  2014
1  1  2014
1  0  2014
1  1  2014
1  1  2014
;
run;

Proc format;
  value gender  0="boy"
                1= "girl";
  value q1f     0= "No"
                1="Yes";
run;

Proc format;
   picture test (round) low-high=0.000.009(mult=0.1);
run;

Proc tabulate data=have;
class gender q1 year;
table gender*(pctn<q1>*F=test.), year*q1;
format gender gender. q1 q1f.;
run;
```

Comment: Is there some reason you need to create a format instead of just using `*F=8.2`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a picture format and you shouldn't need the MULT portion. Not sure why you have that first period and 0.

```
proc format;                           
picture mypct (round) low-high='009.99%';   
run;
```

Source: https://support.sas.com/kb/38/001.html

PROC TABULATE offers a lot more control over the output than PROC FREQ will and is a similar procedure.